# Is quilt broken on High Sierra?

Tags: homebrew, macos, high-sierra

I'm trying to use quilt to manage a patch set. I installed it with brew, but I'm having problems adding files to the patch series. When I add a file, I get an error that stat cannot read file system information for the file in question. Like so:

```
myuser@myComputer quilt-wifi-combo-fw (master) $ quilt add "repos/GORP-SDK/GORP-SDK-6.1.0/77nnn_Li-Fo/version.txt"
stat: cannot read file system information for '%l': No such file or directory
stat: cannot read file system information for '%l': No such file or directory
Failed to back up file repos/GORP-SDK/GORP-SDK-6.1.0/77nnn_Li-Fo/version.txt
myuser@myComputer quilt-wifi-combo-fw (master) $
```

The file does get added to the patch, but doesn't work properly—it seems like it is hard-linked instead of being copied.

Comment: Please provide us with the command you run to get the error message. It seems quilt is not broken, but your command line arguments are.

Comment: That's definitely possible! I've updated my question with the full message and command.